# How do i set value to a variable ASP classic?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Trying to get value from a DataBase and set to a variable, like this :

```
Dim prefferedAgencieUser
Dim agenciePermission

sSql = "SELECT ag.UserTeamLeader "
sSQL = sSQL &  " FROM dbo.BigAgencies ag "
sSQL = sSQL &  " inner join TCL01_cliente cl on cl.preferred_agency=ag.id "
sSQL = sSQL &  " where cl.Cod_cliente = '" & nCodCliente & "'"

Set prefferedAgencieUser = oSelect.ExecuteQuery(sSql)

if prefferedAgencieUser = UserName then
agenciePermission = 1
end if
```

The connection to the DB works well, but i got an error like:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch
```

What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim prefferedAgencieUser 'This is your recordset object
Dim agenciePermission 'This is a variable
Dim sSql 'This is a variable holding your SQL statement

'oSelect - this is your database connection

sSql = "SELECT ag.UserTeamLeader "
sSQL = sSQL &  " FROM dbo.BigAgencies ag "
sSQL = sSQL &  " inner join TCL01_cliente cl on cl.preferred_agency=ag.id "
sSQL = sSQL &  " where cl.Cod_cliente = '" & nCodCliente & "'"

Set prefferedAgencieUser = oSelect.Execute(sSql)

if prefferedAgencieUser.EOF then
    'No record returned from database query
    agenciePermission = 0
ELSE
    'Record(s) returned from database query
    agenciePermission = 1

    UserTeamLeader = prefferedAgencieUser("UserTeamLeader") 'This sets a variable UserTeamLeader to the value returned from the database
end if
```

Comment: I still have same error at the following line :                        if prefferedAgencieUser.EOF then